# Unexpected end of file in php

Tags: php, html

this is the error message i am getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectwxyz\include_files\payment_download.class.php on line 96
>   Can some one help me out

```
if ($query) {

    $message_reciever='jtime@yahoo.com';
    $admin_message_subject = 'pect Payment Information';
    $admin_message = "<div style='background-color:#eeeeee;padding:2%;'>
            <div style='margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%; text-align:center; background-color:white;'>
            <div style='background-color:#9a3bf2; padding-bottom:2%;padding-top:2%;'><img src=\"repertory/img/mainlogo.jpg\" width=\"40px\" height=\"40px\"></div>
            <p><strong><h1>Hi, $message_reciever</h1></strong></p>
                <hr>
            <p>Your payment information has been successfully submited to <a href=\"http://www.pject.com\">pject</a></p>
            <p>Here are your payment information</p>
            <p>Depositors Name: $depositors_name</p>
            <p>Transaction id: $transaction_id</p>
            <p>Bank Paid To: $bank_name</p>
            <p>Email: $email</p>
            <p>Phone Number: $phone</p>
            <p>Department: $department</p>
            <p>Project Material Code: $material_code</p>

            <p>Your download code will be sent to you 20 - 45mins after your payment is confirmed.</p>
            <p>We are more intrested in your Academic success.</p><br>
            <p><strong>Thanks for using our platform. We are more intrested in your Academic success. Let your friends know about Projectwxyz by clicking the facebook share button on our page.</strong></p>
            <a href=\"http://www.pect.com\">Continue.</a>
            </div>
            </div>";

    $message_body = <<<EOD
    $admin_message
            EOD;

    $message_header = "From: no-reply@pect.com\n";
    $message_header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $message_header .="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \n";
    @mail($message_reciever, $admin_message_subject , $message_body, $message_header);

    echo '<div class="success_message"> Your payment information was sent successfully. A download code will be sent to your email 20 - 45mins after your payment is confirmed.</div>';

}else{

    echo '<div class="danger_message"> An error occurred. Try again later.</div>';

}
```

Comment: Can you see what's on the line `96` or tell us which line is that ?

Comment: which is the line number 96..??

Comment: there is no code on line 96

Comment: What do you mean by`$message_body = <<<EOD` and `$admin_message
            EOD;`?

Comment: the broblem is with `$message_body = <<<EOD
    $admin_message
            EOD;`

Comment: As the docs of heredoc say, the terminating string (`EOD;`) must be the first thing on a line, with no whitespace before it.

Comment: **Warning: It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier _may not be indented_, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.** http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

There should be no whitespace before the last `EOD;`

```
<?php

if ($query) {

    $message_reciever      = 'jtime@yahoo.com';
    $admin_message_subject = 'pect Payment Information';
    $admin_message         = "<div style='background-color:#eeeeee;padding:2%;'>
            <div style='margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%; text-align:center; background-color:white;'>
            <div style='background-color:#9a3bf2; padding-bottom:2%;padding-top:2%;'><img src=\"repertory/img/mainlogo.jpg\" width=\"40px\" height=\"40px\"></div>
            <p><strong><h1>Hi, $message_reciever</h1></strong></p>
                <hr>
            <p>Your payment information has been successfully submited to <a href=\"http://www.pject.com\">pject</a></p>
            <p>Here are your payment information</p>
            <p>Depositors Name: $depositors_name</p>
            <p>Transaction id: $transaction_id</p>
            <p>Bank Paid To: $bank_name</p>
            <p>Email: $email</p>
            <p>Phone Number: $phone</p>
            <p>Department: $department</p>
            <p>Project Material Code: $material_code</p>

            <p>Your download code will be sent to you 20 - 45mins after your payment is confirmed.</p>
            <p>We are more intrested in your Academic success.</p><br>
            <p><strong>Thanks for using our platform. We are more intrested in your Academic success. Let your friends know about Projectwxyz by clicking the facebook share button on our page.</strong></p>
            <a href=\"http://www.pect.com\">Continue.</a>
            </div>
            </div>";

    $message_body = <<<EOD
    $admin_message
EOD;



    $message_header = "From: no-reply@pect.com\n";
    $message_header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $message_header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \n";
    @mail($message_reciever, $admin_message_subject, $message_body, $message_header);

    echo '<div class="success_message"> Your payment information was sent successfully. A download code will be sent to your email 20 - 45mins after your payment is confirmed.</div>';

} else {

    echo '<div class="danger_message"> An error occurred. Try again later.</div>';

}
```